# What is an idiomatic French equivalent of the English expression "locked into"?

Tags: expressions, anglais

> While many people believe that they are "locked" into using Microsoft Word for all their document creation needs, it simply isn't true.

L’expression anglaise "be locked into doing something" s’emploie surtout dans le cadre du travail, et par extension, elle s'applique aussi au cas où on se voit inéluctablement contraint de faire un choix par défaut, ou ne serait-ce que pour hurler avec les loups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans l'exemple que tu proposes on pourrait dire :

- > beaucoup de gens pensent qu'ils sont assujettis à se servir de (à l'utilisation de)...

  [TLF assujettir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/assujettir) : « Imposer quelque chose soit en obligeant ou en contraignant, ... »
  Le mot « assujettir» est le mot juridique utilisé dans les contrats d'utilisation<sup>1</sup> mais peut très bien être employé quand la contrainte est subjective et uniquement dans la tête de celui qui y croit, comme c'est le cas dans ton exemple.
- > beaucoup de gens pensent qu'ils sont asservis à utilisation de...

  [TLF asservir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/asservir) : « Réduire à l'esclavage; *p. ext*. mettre sous son entière dépendance. »
  « Asservir » est plus éloigné de la contrainte juridique.

De façon moins soutenue on peut dire aussi :

> beaucoup de gens pensent qu'ils sont coincés par Microsoft dans l'utilisation de...

ou

> beaucoup de gens pensent qu'ils sont enfermés dans l'utilisation de...

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Vous acceptez également que votre utilisation des services puisse être assujettie aux ententes conclues entre Microsoft et vous...](https://www.microsoft.com/fr-ca/servicesagreement/)</sub>